# How to append name with messages in chat program by using twilio?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twilio, twilio-api

I am  creating a chat web app in angular with twilio api. Currently my chat is showing and users can send messages but i want to show which user is currently  sending message.

following is my http post request to twilio

```
 viewMessages():Observable<any>{
 return 
 this.http.get("https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/"+
 this.serviceId+"/Channels/"+this.myChannelId+
"/Messages",this.httpOpt).pipe(map(data=>data));
}
```

following is type  script function

```
  name=localStorage.getItem('name');
  allMessages=[];
  totalMessages:number;
  //View all messages
  viewMessage(){
  console.log(this.name);
   this.chatBox.viewMessages().subscribe(res=>{
    this.allMessages=res.messages
  },
 err=>{
  console.log(err);
    })

}
```

and then i am showing names by interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the messages array and append name to it.

```
this.allMessages.forEach((message, index)=>{
    return this.allMessages[index] = `${this.name}: ${message}`;
});

console.log(this.allMessages);
```

Comment: where i should use this loop like inside viewMessage or elsewhere

Comment: After this line. this.allMessages=res.messages.

Comment: it is giving no error but my messages are not visible

Comment: can i share git?

Comment: also if you can tell me when i am displaying my channel,how can i directly join them on click..right now it is just displaying channels name.Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry  i think i am getting desperate ...if you don't have much work then you solve my display problem otherwise it okay..still thanks